# Episode from "The Fairly OddParents" where Timmy replaced his German teacher with a lumberjack

Tags: cartoon, episode-identification

I am looking for an episode from *The Fairly OddParents* where Timmy replaced his German teacher with a lumberjack.

I can only remember that it was a lumberjack, who said something like "Enough studying German! Let's dance!". Timmy replaced the teacher because he was bored and didn't want to study... if I remember it right. Also, the lumberjack was in something like people singing yodeling usually wear, I suppose. Something like a lederhosen. And it was somewhere in the middle of the episode.

The man was like square-shaped, I am not sure, but with an axe. And Timmy brought him from the woods, where he and more men were working with trees. It was a very small moment in an episode and the German teacher was shown very briefly. I remember the clothes, as I said, and a book thrown away. And the phrase about dancing. And the wand was in Timmy's hands, probably.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F. Do you remember any more details about the episode that can help us identify it. For example, why did Timmy replace the teacher, was it a mechanical woodchopper, or a lumberjack? What was the general story of the episode? Anything you remember would be helpfull.

Comment: Hi,thank you!I can only remember that it was a lumberjack,who said something like "Enough studying German! Let's dance!". Timmy replaced the teacher because he was bored and didn't want to study...if I remember it right.Also the lumberjack was in something like usually people singing yodeling wear,I suppose.

Comment: You mean [Lederhosen](https://images.google.com/images?q=lederhosen)?

Comment: [Suspendees and a bra?](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FshU58nI0Ts)

Comment: There's definitely an episode where there was a [substitute teacher](https://fairlyoddparents.fandom.com/wiki/Ms._Doombringer), but it doesn't match the other details.

Comment: Yes,something like a Lederhosen. And it was somewhere in the middle of the episode.

Comment: Is there anything else you can remember that happened in this episode? [This guide on Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/76048) may help you with remembering certain details you've forgotten or didn't include.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you're thinking of **"[German Squirmin'](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0892629/?ref_=ttep_ep16)"**, S01E16 of *[The Replacements](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816401/)*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Replacements_(TV_series)):

> *The Replacements* is an American animated television series that aired on Disney Channel from July 28, 2006, to March 30, 2009. 52 episodes were produced.

From [The Replacements Wiki](https://the-replacements.fandom.com/wiki/German_Squirmin%27):

> Agent K promises to bring Todd to the The Fun O' Sphere if he gets good grades. However, **Todd is failing German class. He replaces his German teacher with someone who speaks only German in time for parent-teacher night.**
>
> [...]
>
> That afternoon, **Todd asks Conrad Fleem to replace the German teacher with someone who only speaks German, thus becoming incomprehensible to his parents. Fleemco ships the German teacher off to Germany. At the parent-teacher conference, Todd and his father meet Herr Doofentanzer, a German lederhosen-wearing dancer.** Since Dick does not understand German at all, Todd easily fools him into thinking Herr Doofentanzer is praising Todd's good grades. **Dick, Todd, and Doofentanzer break into a happy dance, and Doofentanzer insults Mr. Daring's dancing in German.** Todd runs back to Agent K and Riley, ecstatic about going to the Fun-O-Sphere. **Riley peers into the German class and sees Herr Doofentanzer playing the accordion.**

It's a different series, obviously, but seems to match your description in every other respect.

[image: Screenshot from the episode "German Squirmin" of "The Replacements". Dick Daring and Todd Daring are dancing, with Herr Doofentanzer holding an accordian. The subtitles say "You look like a cow dancing."]

Comment: No,that was definitely in Timmy and The Fairy Odd Parents and it was a real lumberjack speaking English with an accent.He also has thrown a book from the window before starting to dance.

Comment: @Lizuza - Can you explain why you're certain that the character in question was a lumberjack specifically? You haven't mentioned anything about the character carrying an axe or chainsaw, for example, and lumberjacks aren't generally known for dancing or wearing lederhosen. What you've described sounds much more like a traditional German folk dancer, unless you've left out some key details.

Comment: @Lizuza - Also, no German teacher is listed on the [Fairly Odd Parents Wiki page for the school faculty](https://fairlyoddparents.fandom.com/wiki/Category:School_faculty).

Comment: The man was like square shaped,I am not sure,but with an axe and Timmy brought him from the wood where he and more men were working with trees.It was a very small moment in an episode and the German teacher was shown very briefly.I remember the clothes,as I said and a book thrown away.And the phrase about dancing.And the wand was in Timmy's hands,probably.

Comment: @Lizuza - Okay, I've added those extra details to your question. If you think of anything else, feel free to edit the question yourself.